# Google Cloud Build Enabling docker experimental

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

The image created in cloud build are very large. I have tried docker build --squash but it returns squash allowed on experimental. cloudbuild is pretty standard

steps:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
      ['-c', 'docker build --squash --memory-swap=-1 -t eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_IMAGE_TAG} -f ${_IMAGE_NAME}/Dockerfile .']
  env:
   - "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1"
```

Push

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_IMAGE_TAG}']
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

is there a way to enable experimental on gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker

```
starting build "dbeb1aa6-51ba-49f7-ba9d-e9eba6b8b23b"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://dockerbuild-371810_cloudbuild/source/1677598229.965483-0443cf8b0b63486cb4451ffdd45f338a.tgz#1677598230384010
Copying gs://dockerbuild-371810_cloudbuild/source/1677598229.965483-0443cf8b0b63486cb4451ffdd45f338a.tgz#1677598230384010...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/ 10.6 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][ 10.6 KiB/ 10.6 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/10.6 KiB.                                     
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "Enable Experimental"
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental": Client: Docker Engine - Community
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Version:           20.10.14
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  API version:       1.41
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Go version:        go1.16.15
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Git commit:        a224086
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Built:             Thu Mar 24 01:48:02 2022
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Context:           default
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Experimental:      true
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental": 
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental": Server: Docker Engine - Community
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  Engine:
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Version:          20.10.23
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Go version:       go1.18.10
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Git commit:       6051f14
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:32:04 2023
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Experimental:     false
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  containerd:
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Version:          1.6.15
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   GitCommit:        5b842e528e99d4d4c1686467debf2bd4b88ecd86
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  runc:
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Version:          1.1.4
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":  docker-init:
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   Version:          0.19.0
Step #0 - "Enable Experimental":   GitCommit:        de40ad0
Finished Step #0 - "Enable Experimental"
Starting Step #1 - "build"
Step #1 - "build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1 - "build": "--squash" is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental features enabled
Finished Step #1 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: The runtime context are swapped between each step. If you activated the experimental feature in step 0 and use it in step 1, the step 1 is not aware of the previous activation, it start from the beginning. So, perform the experimental activation and usage in the same step.

Comment: how do i perform the activation on the same step?

Comment: Please, edit your question and share your Cloud Build yaml file. We will help you!

Comment: Did you try to set the DOCKER_BUILDKIT env var in the 2nd step also?

Comment: No i did not, the step 2 is only pushing the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252230/discussion-between-fabio-geraci-and-guillaume-blaquiere).